# Set lower limit of number of stars shown in RatingBar Android

Tags: java, android, android-widget, widget

With the RatingBar widget in android you can set the number of stars to be show, but is there a way of setting a lower limit on the number of stars that are always active. As an example rating a film or something where you cannot submit a rating of 1?

Comment: you can explicitlity set the rating to be bounded to any value suppose 2 if lower than that bound it to 2 onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
   boolean fromUser) In these any value suppose   1 if lower than that bound it to 2 in code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is not possible in the framework strictyl speaking, you could put a default value of 1 with `android:rating` set to 1, and the add a listener on the `RatingBar` to go back to 1 when the user tries to go lower no?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works I just feel it's quite messy code.

Comment: check Paresh's answer for  more detailled version of mine. It's not really messy.

Answer (score 6):

*is there a way of setting a lower limit on the number of stars that are always active.*

Yes you can set the Rating using `setRating()` method.
For example:

```
ratingBar.setRating(rat);
```

*As an example rating a film or something where you cannot submit a rating of 1?*

For this, you have to implement a condition inside the onRatingChanged() method.
for example:

```
ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

    @Override public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, 
      boolean fromUser) {
        // implement your condition here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   <RatingBar android:id="@+id/ratingbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="1.0"
    android:rating="1"/>
```

By setting rating =1 it is shows rating 1.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @sephy supporting his answer. I am adding a sample code which I have used in my app.

```
mRatingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
            if(selectedRating<=0) {
                mRatingBar.setRating(1);
            }
       }
    });
```