# How to set rating bar to minimum one star?

Tags: android, actionlistener, ratingbar

I have a requirement to rate for a user with minimum of one star and after that ratings should increase to 0.5. But my question is that the user should not change the minimum rating of star to 0.5 or 0. 1 should be the default rating. Please help with this and awaiting for your earlier response. I also tried implementing by listeners from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583637/set-lower-limit-of-number-of-stars-shown-in-ratingbar-android) but completely struct with the logic inside
**My code is:**

```
ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

    @Override public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, 
      boolean fromUser) {

    }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set lower limit of number of stars shown in RatingBar Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583637/set-lower-limit-of-number-of-stars-shown-in-ratingbar-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting Rating takes float value ,
in Case ur value is String :

```
ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat(result));
```

Answer (score 29):

```
 ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

@Override public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, 
  boolean fromUser) {
     if(rating<1.0f)
          ratingBar.setRating(1.0f);
}
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                                boolean fromUser) {
            Toast.makeText(RateUsProductActivity.this,"Rating :-  "+String.valueOf(rating),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(rating<1.0f)
            ratingBar.setRating(1.0f);
    }
});
```

**When Rating is less than 1 then automatically set Rating 1**

**Happy Coding Cheers!**

Answer (score 1):

Setting OnRatingBarChangeListener will work, but the problem with this solution is that if you try to drag rating below 1 star, it will show zero stars for a second, and only then will jump back to desirable 1 star. To avoid this "flickering" behavior I sugest to inherit `RatingBar` and override method `getMin`. For example:

```
class MinStarRatingBar @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : AppCompatRatingBar(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private var minStars = 0

    fun setMinimumStars(minStars: Int) {
        this.minStars = minStars
    }

    override fun getMin(): Int {
        return minStars
    }
}
```

And then just use `ratingBar.setMinimumStars(/*your value*/)`

**NOTE**: I don't know why, but `setMin` method just isn't working. It requires minimum Api 26 to run, and changes the change step in Ratinbar and does not affect min value of stars for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
      ratingbar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                boolean fromUser) {

                  ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat(""+Math.ceil(rating)));
                }
 }
```