# Setting the minimum stars to a rating bar

Tags: java, rating, ratingbar

I have a rating bar where I want the user to choose from 1 to 5 stars, and I have used the stepSize = "1" which eliminates decimals.

However, the user can still choose 0 star rating, is there a way in xml attributes specifically where I limit the star rating options to 1-5 instead of 0-5?

I have found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26360086/how-to-set-rating-bar-to-minimum-one-star), but the solution is in Java code, where you make an if statement and changing the 0 to 1.

I'm asking if I can limit the option to 1-5 using the xml attributes of the rating bar somehow.

Comment: Then what is your `language` ??

Comment: It is Java, but what I meant is that I don't want to solve this by letting the user choose 0 and then changing it to one, I'm asking if I can make the minimum option for the rating bar to 1 star, so that a 0 star is not even an option.

Comment: is [this](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-rating-bar-example/) helpful?

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks It appears that he was mistaken about the minimum of the rating bar being 1 stars, there's a comment that corrects him, and from what I understand from that comment is that there's no simple way to change it in the xml attributes.